# make changes across multiple reactive environments in Shiny to avoid code redundancy

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

Say I have a really basic Shiny setup like this:

```
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$plot_1 <- renderPlot({ 
    DF <- DF[which(DF$column==input$num), ]
    p <- ggplot()
      ...
    plot(p))}
```

Everything is great. So, after this I've created another ggplot, with is based on the same input, except for one extra line of code:
        output$plot_2 <- renderPlot({

```
    DF <- DF[which(DF$column==input$num), ]
    DF <- *doing something different here*
    p <- ggplot()
      ...
    plot(p))}
```

So I've gone ahead and created 10 of these plots, all slight variations of each other. Basically, they all differ by one or two lines, yet are all unique. (Rest assured, I've used the `grid` package to squeeze them all onto one page, and it doesn't look half bad).

No prob! But I'm starting to get some philosophical questions.

For every single plot, Shiny is forced to reinvent (most of) the wheel. I am:

1) Getting boated code
2) Rerunning the same operations for each plot -- for example, all the work where the dataframe is subsetted by `input$num`, etc, which is consistent across plots.

Why and I getting this? Because, as far as I can tell, the scope within each `renderPlot` is local. I can't globally modify my dataframe outside of any individual reactive function. To prove it, if I try to pull the code outside the reactive call:

```
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    DF <- DF[which(DF$column==input$num), ] #no longer within the renderPlot call

    output$plot_1 <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot()
      ...
    plot(p))}
```

I get the error

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

My plots are appearing slowly and clumsily. There is a horrendous amount of code (over 90%) being run ten times that I feel should be run once!

My question is this:  how can I best reuse modifications across reactive environments? How can I make one single input (say, `input$num`) affect my dataframe once, and have the changes made available to all 10 of my outputs?

Comment: Put the changes to the data in a reactive and call it where needed. The code in the reactive will be be run once per data change no matter how many plots you make. Or put the data in a reactiveValues

Comment: It would be so awesome if you elaborated this into an official answer! PS Merry Xmas to ya

Comment: I assume you have enough to go on Mikael's answer. You can put DF before the shinyServer call to make it global. If you have multiple datasets use a reactiveValues list to store them in. Not tested but I don't think you need makeReacktiveBing in Mikael's example

Answer (score 1):

Single file app about using of `makeReactiveBinding()`.

```
library(shiny)
    server <- function(input, output) {
      DF <- data.frame(c(2,3,5), c("aa", "bb", "cc"), c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
      makeReactiveBinding("DF")

      modifData <- reactive({
        DF <- DF[,input$num, drop=FALSE]
      })


      output$dataTable <- renderDataTable({
        # Data modification is now done in reactive expression which caches the value, which means 
        # that calculation is done again only when input$num changes
        DF <- modifData()
        # Unique modifications here
        return(DF)
      })
    }

    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          sliderInput("num", "Column:", min = 1, max = 3, value = 1)
        ),
        mainPanel(dataTableOutput("dataTable"))
      )
    ))

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```